# Simple functions in Rust in the release version do not appear in the symbol table

Tags: rust, linker, shared-libraries, symbols, rlib

I created a Rust crate with `cargo new --lib zero_obj`，then write a very simple function:

```
pub fn test_function_base001() -> i32 {
    2
}
```

and compile the release version with `cargo build --release`.

When I look at the symbol table of the rlib file:

```
readelf -sW libzero_obj.rlib 

File: libzero_obj.rlib(lib.rmeta)

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 1 entry:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 

File: libzero_obj.rlib(zero_obj-68a8e959160a6c87.zero_obj.e381423afbee4894-cgu.0.rcgu.o)

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 3 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS zero_obj.e381423afbee4894-cgu.0
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 $d.0
```

I found that the `pub fn test_function_base001` I wrote was not in the symbol table, so where did my function go? It is defined as a public function, which may be referenced by any other crate.

When the output file is a shared library, with a `[lib]` section like this:

```toml
[lib]
name = "zero_obj"
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

the function is not available in the produced `.so`-file either.

Comment: Try `[profile.release]
opt-level = 0
`

Comment: A dylib is a *rust-ABI (unstable)* dynamic library, I'm not sure it uses standard symbol tables. And your reports are inconsistents since the readelf output you show is for an rlib, which is a *statically linked rust-ABI library*, that's even less likely to use anything standard as I assume it needs to support things like uninstantiated generic functions. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: AFAIK, to get an exported symbol you need to declare your function as `#[no_mangle]`. Maybe you should always use a `extern "C"` or similar, but that depends on what you intend to do with the library.

Comment: The function is likely removed due to dead code elimination; ensure it's used or marked with `#[no_mangle]` and `pub extern "C"` if you need it to be preserved.